# Jquery .val() will not update textbox on screen

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

A really weird issue. I'm providing some buttons on a form that are supposed to auto-populate some fields (textboxes). The values that are supposed to be inserted into the textboxes are javascript functions to be evaluated. But even if I just try and put plain text in there, they don't update.

The buttons that set these values appear to set the value on the textbox properly because I have another button that evaluates the values. But the textbox remains empty on the screen and when looking at the markup with F12 tools, I see nothing.

And I apologize ahead of time for the poor formatting. I just wanted to use a JFiddle link to make things short and sweet, but Stackoverflow won't let me. Arg.

https://jsfiddle.net/ox5cat40/

```
<div class="container-row">
    <div id="DateValidationPanel"></div>
    <div id="StartEndDateButtons" class="container-row">
      <button id="ScheduleTodayButton">Today</button>
      <button id="ScheduleLast24Button">Last 24 Hours</button>
      <button id="ScheduleLastWeekButton">Last Week</button>
      <button id="ScheduleCurrentMonthButton">Current Month</button>
      <button id="EvaluateButton">Verify Start &amp; End Dates</button>
    </div>
  <table id="ScheduleParametersTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="schedule-td-1">Parameter</th>
      <th class="schedule-td-2">Type</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Parameters_0__Id" name="Parameters[0].Id" type="hidden" value="0">
          <input id="Parameters_0__Name" name="Parameters[0].Name" type="hidden" value="PSTART_DATE">
          <input id="Parameters_0__DisplayText" name="Parameters[0].DisplayText" type="hidden" value="Start Date">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ParameterId must be a number." data-val-required="The ParameterId field is required." id="Parameters_0__ParameterId" name="Parameters[0].ParameterId" type="hidden" value="422">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DotNetTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The DotNetTypeId field is required." id="Parameters_0__DotNetTypeId" name="Parameters[0].DotNetTypeId" type="hidden" value="3">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CaptureTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The CaptureTypeId field is required." id="Parameters_0__CaptureTypeId" name="Parameters[0].CaptureTypeId" type="hidden" value="3">
          <input id="Parameters_0__CaptureType" name="Parameters[0].CaptureType" type="hidden" value="">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Ordering must be a number." data-val-required="The Ordering field is required." id="Parameters_0__Ordering" name="Parameters[0].Ordering" type="hidden" value="1">
          <input id="Parameters_0__DropDownQueryName" name="Parameters[0].DropDownQueryName" type="hidden" value="">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DropDownQueryProjectId must be a number." id="Parameters_0__DropDownQueryProjectId" name="Parameters[0].DropDownQueryProjectId" type="hidden" value="">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DropDownQueryParam must be a number." id="Parameters_0__DropDownQueryParam" name="Parameters[0].DropDownQueryParam" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Parameters_0__Value" name="Parameters[0].Value" type="hidden" value="((new Date()).getMonth()) + &quot;/&quot; + ((new Date()).getDate()) + &quot;/&quot; + (new Date()).getFullYear()">
          <input id="Parameters_0__ScheduledValue" name="Parameters[0].ScheduledValue" type="hidden" value="var d = new Date();(d.getMonth()+1) + '/1/'+d.getFullYear();">
          <input id="Parameters_0__Type" name="Parameters[0].Type" type="hidden" value="DynamicReport.Models.ReportParameter">
          <input id="Parameters_0__DropDownValue" name="Parameters[0].DropDownValue" type="hidden" value="">
          Start Date
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
<input id="Parameters_0__ScheduledValue" name="Parameters[0].ScheduledValue" type="text" class="scheduled-value"/>         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Parameters_1__Id" name="Parameters[1].Id" type="hidden" value="0">
          <input id="Parameters_1__Name" name="Parameters[1].Name" type="hidden" value="PEND_DATE">
          <input id="Parameters_1__DisplayText" name="Parameters[1].DisplayText" type="hidden" value="End Date">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ParameterId must be a number." data-val-required="The ParameterId field is required." id="Parameters_1__ParameterId" name="Parameters[1].ParameterId" type="hidden" value="423">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DotNetTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The DotNetTypeId field is required." id="Parameters_1__DotNetTypeId" name="Parameters[1].DotNetTypeId" type="hidden" value="3">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CaptureTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The CaptureTypeId field is required." id="Parameters_1__CaptureTypeId" name="Parameters[1].CaptureTypeId" type="hidden" value="3">
          <input id="Parameters_1__CaptureType" name="Parameters[1].CaptureType" type="hidden" value="">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Ordering must be a number." data-val-required="The Ordering field is required." id="Parameters_1__Ordering" name="Parameters[1].Ordering" type="hidden" value="2">
          <input id="Parameters_1__DropDownQueryName" name="Parameters[1].DropDownQueryName" type="hidden" value="">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DropDownQueryProjectId must be a number." id="Parameters_1__DropDownQueryProjectId" name="Parameters[1].DropDownQueryProjectId" type="hidden" value="">
          <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DropDownQueryParam must be a number." id="Parameters_1__DropDownQueryParam" name="Parameters[1].DropDownQueryParam" type="hidden" value="">
          <input id="Parameters_1__Value" name="Parameters[1].Value" type="hidden" value="((new Date()).getMonth()+1) + &quot;/&quot; +(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 0)).getDate() + &quot;/&quot; + (new Date()).getFullYear()">
          <input id="Parameters_1__ScheduledValue" name="Parameters[1].ScheduledValue" type="hidden" value="((new Date()).getMonth()+1)+'/'+(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()+1,0)).getDate()+'/'+(new Date()).getFullYear();">
          <input id="Parameters_1__Type" name="Parameters[1].Type" type="hidden" value="DynamicReport.Models.ReportParameter">
          <input id="Parameters_1__DropDownValue" name="Parameters[1].DropDownValue" type="hidden" value="">
          End Date
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
<input id="Parameters_1__ScheduledValue" name="Parameters[1].ScheduledValue" type="text" class="scheduled-value"/>     </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div> 

      var today = "var d = new Date();(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/'+d.getFullYear();";
  var yesterday = "var d = new Date();d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/'+d.getFullYear();";
  var sevenDaysAgo = "var d = new Date();d.setDate(d.getDate()-7);(d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/'+d.getFullYear();";
  var firstOfCurrentMonth = "var d = new Date();(d.getMonth()+1) + '/1/'+d.getFullYear();";
  var lastOfCurrentMonth = "((new Date()).getMonth()+1)+'/'+(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()+1,0)).getDate()+'/'+(new Date()).getFullYear();";

 function evalDate(dateType, input) {
    var result;
    try {
      var dateResult = eval(input);
      result = "<span class='date-valid'>" + dateType + ": " + dateResult + "</span><br/>";
    } catch (ex) {
      result = "<span class='date-error'>" + dateType + ": Syntax Error</span><br/>";
    }

    return result;
  }

   $("#EvaluateButton").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var result;

      $("#DateValidationPanel").html("");
      $("input[name$='DisplayText']").each(function () {

        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("start") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));

          result = evalDate("Start Date", $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val());
          $("#DateValidationPanel").append(result);
        }

        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("end") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));

          result = evalDate("End Date", $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val());
          $("#DateValidationPanel").append(result);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

    $("#ScheduleTodayButton").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("input[name$='DisplayText']").each(function () {

        // Set Start Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("start") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(today);
        }

        // Set End Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("end") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(today);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

    $("#ScheduleLast24Button").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("input[name$='DisplayText']").each(function () {
        // Set Start Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("start") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(yesterday);
        }

        // Set End Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("end") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(today);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

    $("#ScheduleLastWeekButton").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("input[name$='DisplayText']").each(function () {

        // Set Start Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("start") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(sevenDaysAgo);
        }

        // Set End Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("end") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(today);
        }
      });
       return false;
    });


    $("#ScheduleCurrentMonthButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input[name$='DisplayText']").each(function () {

        // Set Start Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("start") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(firstOfCurrentMonth);
        }

        // Set End Date
        if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf("end") >= 0) {
          index = $("input[name$='DisplayText']").index($(this));
          $("input[name$='ScheduledValue']").eq(index).val(lastOfCurrentMonth);
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
```

what is happening here?

Comment: Not clear what we should be seeing in demo. There are a ton of hidden inputs and the visible start one seems to update fine. Also ...are these buttons inside a form? If so need to set `type="button"` or they will submit the form

Comment: The "return false" prevents form submission. The hidden elements are part of the larger page. I just copied and pasted from the project we're working on. I didn't bother to pare it down. If the update is working for you... amazing. I cannot get either field to update in Chrome or IE.

Comment: So. Much. Text.    Could you narrow it down a bit, by like 90%? This looks like Code Review posting...

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kondrad. Got me looking at the hidden elements and I saw that the textfield was duplicated as a hidden element. That was the problem. All solved.